# how can i send resultset in JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, resultset

i am building a web service in java 
and my client is .net
for example my table contains String "name",String "surname", and Integer "id" and i want to send all of them
my question is, which type should the method return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it would be some custom type like:

```
class Person {
   String name;
   String surname;
   Integer id;
   // constructor etc.
}
```